# Why Java-app doesn't see external logback.xml location?

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, logback

I have java Spring (not Spring Boot) app, which is launched in Kubernetes using Docker. I'm trying to set the path to logback.xml via parameters, but my app doesn't see it.

In my dockerfile I have this line for launching my app:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","run/app.jar","-Xms128m","-Xmx4096m","-Dlogback.configurationFile=/logconfig/logback.xml","--spring.config.location=file:///appconfig/application.properties"]
```

logback.xml is placed to the pod via ConfigMap and Deployment.yaml,

I have such directory structure in the pod:

```
/
/run/app.jar
/logconfig/logback.xml
```

If I move to the run folder and try to cat config file (like this: `@w:/run# cat /logconfig/logback.xml` ) inside my launched pod I receive correct output. So, this means I do really have /logconfig/logback.xml in a place I expect it to be.

Also, I have no logback.xml inside my jar-file (I have excluded it in the configuration of packaging in pom.xml)

If it matters in some way, as an OS inside the pod I have Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye).

For logging I use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.16</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

So, what is wrong in my configuration, why my app doesn't see my external logback.xml?

PS: by doesn't see I mean that if I place logback.xml inside jar-file, when launching the app, I receive some output in logs about logback configuration plus logback uses that logging level, which I specify in logback.xml. But if I delete logback.xml from jar-file, then there is no information in logs about logback configuration, plus, it doesn't matter what log level is set in logback.xml, logs will always be on DEBUG level.